# Prove a matrix is Hermitian using bra ket notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

Given the operator 
$$\hat{p} = \sqrt{2mt}\sum_j[i\left|j-1\right\rangle \left\langle j|-i|j+1\right\rangle\left\langle j \right|]$$
I want to show that $\hat{p} = \hat{p}^{\dagger}$

My thoughts were the following

$$\begin{align} \hat{p}^{\dagger} &= (\sqrt{2mt}\sum_j[i\left|j-1\right\rangle \left\langle j|-i|j+1\right\rangle\left\langle j \right|])^{\dagger}\\ &=  \sqrt{2mt}\sum_j ([i\left|j-1\right\rangle \left\langle j|-i|j+1\right\rangle\left\langle j \right|])^{\dagger}
\end{align} $$

Now I'm stuck. (I realize I didn't came that far ;-)).
My question is the following, how does the complex conjugate work on bra's and kets?

**Update**
Is it correct to say the following?

$$\begin{align} \hat{p}^{\dagger} &= (\sqrt{2mt}\sum_j[i\left|j-1\right\rangle \left\langle j|-i|j+1\right\rangle\left\langle j \right|])^{\dagger}\\ &=  \sqrt{2mt}\sum_j ([i\left|j-1\right\rangle \left\langle j|-i|j+1\right\rangle\left\langle j \right|])^{\dagger} \\ &=
\sqrt{2mt}\sum_j([i\left\langle j \right|)^{\dagger}(\left\langle j \right| -i\left| j+1\right\rangle)^{\dagger}(\left|j-1\right\rangle)^{\dagger}\ \ \ ?
\end{align} $$

Comment: Prove that $(u\otimes v^\ast)^\ast=v \otimes u^\ast$ for any two vectors.

Comment: @PPR I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with that notation (the arrow into the paper)?

Comment: that's how one notates in math the braket notation. It's called a tensor product. Here we take the tensor product of a vector with the dual of another vector, obtaining a vector in $V \otimes V^\ast$, which is isomorphic to $End(V)$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall $(|n\rangle\langle k| )^\dagger =|k\rangle\langle n| $. So, then, complex conjugate and transpose a purely imaginary antisymmetric infinite matrix,
$$  \hat{p}^{\dagger} = \sqrt{2mt}\sum_j  \Bigl (i\left|j-1\right\rangle \left\langle j|~~-i~|j+1\right\rangle\left\langle j \right|\Bigr )^{\dagger}\\ 
= \sqrt{2mt}\sum_j  \Bigl (i\left|j\right\rangle \left\langle j+1|~~-i~|j \right\rangle\left\langle j-1 \right|\Bigr ) =  \hat{p}.$$
The identification with your original expression follows relabelling your dummy indices summed over, $j\mapsto j-1$ and  $j\mapsto j+1$  in the first and second terms inside the sum, respectively.